# Get Likes and Comment count for linkedin post api 2.0

Tags: c#

I have been used Linkedin API 2.0 into my web application. and i have done post images using this api.

Now i want's to get likes and comments count for the post.

Can anyone tell what i need to do.

Comment: Yes, you need to consult the API documentation to find out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/commenting-reading-comments-and-likes-network-updates

The documentation seems well done, you should find what you want in it ! :)

Comment: The link is restricted, is there any solution for this

Comment: same here it shows permission denied even after login.